# How does a django gargoyle percent condition work?

Tags: django, gargoyle

**UPDATE: The test was bunk—see answer. Percentage condition works as expected.**

I expected a test switch with a 50–100 percent condition to behave in the following way:

```
user 1 -> a
user 2 -> b
user 3 -> a
user 4 -> b
```

I thought this type of condition would simply alternate users to fit the percent defined. Apparently not, as this is what actually happened:

```
user 1 -> a
user 2 -> a
user 3 -> a
user 4 -> b
user 5 -> b
user 6 -> b
user 7 -> b
user 8 -> b
user 9 -> b
user 10 -> b
```

Answer (score 0):

The original test I did used emails in this sort of format:

```
garg1+test@test.com
garg2+test@test.com
&c.
```

emails formatted “properly” returned the expected result:

```
garg1@test.com -> a
garg2@test.com -> b
garg3@test.com -> a
garg4@test.com -> b
```

It seems that gargoyle's percent condition works just as you would expect.